# How to pull the external website URL in other public site ?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am working on a widget sort of project. I have an external URL - http://live.cricnepal.com. THis is a scorecard of Cricket (game). Now i want to share this url to the public for ex: making a widget, plugin etc.

I am currently pulling the url with the help of iframe(http://www.cricnepal.com), (http://www.digitec.com.np) and also developed a simple plugin in wordpress with iframe. I need a help from you people on how to pull the url by javascript api, json/np etc, so that i can share this widget to other website owners/fans of cricket.

Looking forward for your help . Cheers! Have a great day.

Comment: Do you have a permission to access that data?

Comment: I have developed the site cricnepal.com and live.cricnepal.com and its on my own hosting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: <?php echo file_get_contents('http://abc.com');?> is good idea but security concern are there.. right ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how to pull the URL and write it.

```
<script>

document.write(location.href);

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code here please. Also, How can we pull the external URL by using <script type="text/javascript" src="score.js"></script>.